# Creating a function that removes duplicates in list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to manually make a function that removes duplicates from a list. I know there is a Python function that does something similar (`set()`), but I want to create my own. This is what I have:

```
def remove(lst):

for i in range(len(lst)):
    aux = lst[0:i] + lst[i+1:len(lst)]
    if lst[i] in aux:
        del(lst[i])

return lst
```

I was trying something like creating a sub-list with all the items except the one the for is currently on, and then check if the item is still in the list. If it is, remove it.

The problem is that it gives me an index out of range error. Does the `for i in range(len(lst)):` line not update every time it starts over? Since I'm removing items from the list, the list will be shorter, so for a list that has 10 items and 2 duplicates, it will go up to index 9 instead of stopping on the 7th.

Is there anyway to fix this, or should I just try doing this is another way?

Comment: You can store all the indices of items you'll need to delete, then handle everything after the loop.

Comment: *should I just try doing this is another way?*  <--- yes, that

Comment: How? I tried doing that, but as soon as I do del(lst[d]) d being a list with all the indexes that are duplicate, it gives me an index out of range error since all the other values of d are now off.

Comment: Iterate through the list of indices from highest to lowest.  Use **for d in lst[::-1]**

Comment: Realize that this is quite inefficient. The `aux = ...` line is O(n). The `lst[i] in aux` check is O(n). `del(list[i])` is O(n). All of these are repeated for each position in the list. Overall you've got O(n^2) performance.

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not fix your current script, but would something like this work?

```
def remove(lst):
    unique=[]
    for i in lst:
        if i not in unique: unique.append(i)
    return unique
```

Just simply looping through, creating another list and checking for membership?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are manipulating the list as you are iterating over it. This means that when you reach the end of the list, it is now shorter because you're removed elements. You should (generally) avoid removing elements while you are looping over lists.

Comment: Yes that's the exact problem, I'll stick with the while as another user mentioned! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got it the first time: **len(lst)** is evaluated only when you enter the loop.  If you want it re-evaluated, try the **while** version:

```
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    ...
    i += 1
```

Next, you get to worry about another problem: you increment i *only* when you don't delete an item.  When you do delete, shortening the list gets you to the next element.

```
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    aux = lst[0:i] + lst[i+1:len(lst)]
    if lst[i] in aux:
        del(lst[i])
    else:
        i += 1
```

I think that should solve your problem ... using the logic you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(lst):
    new_list = []
    for i in lst:
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

You should append the values to a secondary list. As Bobbyrogers [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273108/7067541), it's not a good idea to iterate over a list that is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6]
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    if i not in lst2:
        lst2.append(i)
print(lst2)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```